# Как добавить столбец в таблицу через форму PHP с сохранением в БД

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Есть таблица, через форму добавляются строки с данными и сохраняются в БД MySQL.
Как сделать добавление столбца в текущую таблицу и сохранение ее в БД?

Функционал:
Есть таблица с именами студентов списком слева, а справа добавляются предметы колонками, а в ячейках будут оценки. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Запросить параметры поля, составить и выполнить соответствующий ALTER TABLE. Но лучше не надо - изменение структуры таблиц из клиентского кода есть яркий образец bad practice.

Comment: вообще не делать. вместо этого задать вопрос указав свою структуру таблиц и получить ответ как эту структуру изменить чтобы не приходилось добавлять столбцы на ходу

Comment: Тогда давайте попробую описать задачу, подскажите как лучше это реализовать.
Есть таблица с именами студентов списком слева, а справа добавляются предметы колонками, а в ячейках будут оценки.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: С точки зрения базы данных нужно три таблицы - студенты, предметы, и оценки по предметам с тремя колонками - ид студента, ид предмета, и оценка. но чтобы все это реализовать в виде готового приложения надо сначала выучить программирование, SQL, РНР и HTML. Хотя бы на базовом уровне

Comment: и вообще, какая таблица изначально имелась в виду? таблица в базе данных или таблица с оценками в браузере?